# Exim4, local domain, error 550, Debian

Tags: linux, debian, auth, exim, dovecot

Есть два локальных домена (тестовая кофигурация), для простоты настройки в одной подсети (192.168.х.х), в каждом домене по одной машине, каждая из которых является почтовым сервером для своего домена (Exim4+Dovecot). Домены видят друг друга через MX запись.
Задача - настроить передачу почты между доменами с аутентификацией.
В Exim4 в acl есть правило deny, которое запрещает работу без аутентификации (!authentificated = *), если его убрать, то почта ходит. Пытаюсь разобраться, как настроить Exim4, чтобы почта между доменами ходила без удаления моей acl записи.

К сожалению в Exim4 не силен, поэтому прошу помощи.

Сейчас пришла в голову идея насчет адреса 192.168... может Exim4 считает его локальным и применяет определенные правила релея почты? Просто мне почему-то казалось, что все разруливает MX запись.

Comment: *Задача - настроить передачу почты между доменами с аутентификацией* — требуется подробная расшифровка.

Comment: Попробую расшифровать: При отправке письма из домена1 в домен2 я получаю ошибку SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT TO:<ald-user1@example.ru>:
    host srv1.example.ru [192.168.32.10]: 550 "Auth required". Эта ошибка связана с конфигом 30_exim4-config_check_rcpt, конкретно с секцией deny
    message = "Auth required"
    hosts = *:+relay_from_hosts
    !authenticated = *

Comment: Если секцию убрать, то почта между доменами ходит, но, вероятно без аутентификации

Comment: к сожалению, я был непонят. попробую по-другому. имеется два smtp-сервера. первый из них имеет в очереди почтовое сообщение для второго. как, по-вашему, должна происходить передача этого сообщения? т.е.: кто, как и на основании чего должен проходить [аутентификацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)?